# 1860-1868 Birth Certificate from Hungary

Tags: 19th-century, hungary, transylvania

Can anyone advise me on how to obtain my great-great-grandfather's birth certificate (he was born in Fogaras, Transylvania, Hungary between 1860-1868 [corrected]) and possible renunciation of Hungarian citizenship?

His name is Francisco Lenarduzzi, son of Francesco Antonio Lenarduzzi (Italian) and Anna Bone (Hungarian). I need both documents apostilled for international legal purposes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! If you need documents for legal purposes, I strongly suggest hiring a professional who is experienced in helping clients attain dual citizenship, who will be familiar with the process of getting documents apostilled.  Try the APG website. https://www.apgen.org/cpages/home

Comment: Terminology note: you will not be able to get a "birth certificate", as no such beast exists. In the 1860s in Hungary, official vital records were church registers. What you can get is an official extract from the relevant register, and you'll probably need to hire someone to go do that in person. Romania doesn't believe in making our lives too easy by ::gasp:: putting information online.